C++Builder 12.2 error: "cannot use C++ 'try' in the same function as SEH '__try'"
After a computer crash and reinstallation of C++Builder 12.2 on a new computer, some code doesn't compile any more. For example:
void __fastcall TSynCustomExporter::CopyToClipboardFormat(UINT AFormat)                      
    ...                                                                                          
    try // line 206
    {                                                                                        
        PtrData = ((Byte*) GlobalLock((HGLOBAL) hData));                                       
        if(ASSIGNED(PtrData))                                                                  
        {                                                                                      
            try // line 211
            {                                                                                    
                fBuffer->Position = 0;                                                             
                fBuffer->Read((void**)PtrData, (TNativeCount) (hDataSize - 1)); // trailing #0     
            }                                                                                    
            __finally                                                                            
            {                                                                                    
                GlobalUnlock((HGLOBAL) hData);                                                     
            }                                                                                    
            Clipboard()->SetAsHandle(AFormat, hData);                                            
        }                                                                                      
        else                                                                                   
            Abort();                                                                               
    }                                                                                        
    catch(...)                                                                               
    {                                                                                        
        GlobalFree((HGLOBAL) hData);                                                           
        OutOfMemoryError();                                                                    
    }         

The error message is:
[bcc64x Error] SynEditExport.cpp(206): cannot use C++ 'try' in the same function as SEH '__try'
[bcc64x Hint] SynEditExport.cpp(211): conflicting '__try' here

There are explanations for such error messages for other compilers, but C++Builder has its own special __finally extension to reproduce Delphi behavior.
I found out that there was a patch that is probably responsible for the new behavior:
RSS-698: try catch finally bug under win64x
Unfortunately I can't log in there.
I like to know more about the background of this error message. If the patch is really responsible for it, I wonder whether the patch does not create more errors than fixes errors.

UPDATE:
Thanks for your suggestions to work around the problem. But, to keep my question short, I haven't explained its background sufficiently.
The code example is the result of an automatic conversion of the following Delphi code using the Delphi2CB tool:
procedure TSynCustomExporter.CopyToClipboardFormat(AFormat: UINT);
  ...
  try
    PtrData := GlobalLock(hData);
    if Assigned(PtrData) then
    begin
      try
        fBuffer.Position := 0;
        fBuffer.Read(PtrData^, hDataSize - 1); // trailing #0
      finally
        GlobalUnlock(hData);
      end;
      Clipboard.SetAsHandle(AFormat, hData);
    end
    else
      Abort;
  except
    GlobalFree(hData);
    OutOfMemoryError;
  end;

This conversion is uncomplicated and can be understood immediately by every user.
The example code was taken from the C++ version of the SynEdit components, where the error now occurs frequently. Constructing a special structure for this case would not be a solution for the other cases. Using scope_exit would be a general solution, but not intuitive.
And as I said at the beginning, the problem didn't exist a few weeks ago. I don't understand why the code suddenly stopped working.

Why not just stick to standard C++ anyway. __finally is easily replaced by a scope guard.  (like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit/scope_exit)

You could also create a simple struct that takes a HGLOBAL on construction, and on destruction unlocks and destroys the HGLOBAL.  Then all you need to do is create an instance of that struct before any of those try calls.  Doing that will relieve you from making all of those GlobalUnlock/GlobalFree calls you are doing now, plus you are guaranteed that the handle is unlocked/freed, regardless of the reason for the CopyToClipboardFormat function to return.  Investigate RAII.

"there was a patch that is probably responsible for the new behavior ... Unfortunately I can't log in there" - the bug report simply links to this blog article, which lists RSS-698 as one of the fixed bugs (but the report is still open!). "the problem didn't exist a few weeks ago. I don't understand why the code suddenly stopped working" - were you using the same bcc64x compiler before? Code doesn't just stop working for no reason. Since you did a reinstall, you are likely using a different compiler now

I recommend against mix-and-match SEH mechanism with C++ mechanism.  But if you have your heart set on mixing them, make sure you have enabled the compiler's flags to allow them to be mixed.

Ok, I now understand that that indeed the patch is repponsibel for the new behavior and nothing else (e.g. Windows 11) on my new machine. Of course I don't want to use buggy code.
But I'm still missing an explanation of the bug.  Does the mixing SEH mechanism with C++ mechanism bug only concern the modern compiler or the other compilers too, or even Delphi, though the still allow compilation? If Delphi and the other C++ compilers are working correctly, is there a chance that the mixing will be possible with the modern compiler  again too?

@dmeltz Clang simply does not support mixing C++ try/catch with SEH __try/__except/__finally in the same function, and never has. Borland's bcc32 compiler has always allowed that as a compiler extension. This is documented: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Stricter_C%2B%2B_Compilers_(Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers)#Structural_Syntax "BCC32 allows one to mix __try and catch. Clang-enhanced C++ compilers want try/catch (standard C++) OR __try/__except/__finally (Microsoft extensions)."

I wanted to mark Remy Lebeau's last answer as the best, but couldn't find the "green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer", so I repeat it here:

Clang simply does not support mixing C++ try/catch with SEH __try/__except/__finally in the same function, and never has. Borland's bcc32 compiler has always allowed that as a compiler extension. This is documented:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Stricter_C%2B%2B_Compilers_(Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers)#Structural_Syntax

BCC32 allows one to mix __try and catch. Clang-enhanced C++ compilers want try/catch (standard C++) OR __try/__except/__finally (Microsoft extensions).


I add: before the patch of C++Builder Athens, such mixing compiled, but not any longer. The code for the modern C++ compiler version of Synedit was corrected by using a code guard, similar to what Pepijn Kramer suggested.
void __fastcall TSynCustomExporter::CopyToClipboardFormat(UINT AFormat)
{
  ...
        try
        {
            PtrData = ((Byte*) GlobalLock((HGLOBAL) hData));
            if(ASSIGNED(PtrData))
            {
                {
                    auto olsLambda = onLeavingScope([&] 
                    {
                        GlobalUnlock((HGLOBAL) hData);
                    });
                    fBuffer->Position = 0;
                    fBuffer->Read((void**)PtrData, (TNativeCount) (hDataSize - 1)); // trailing #0
                }
                Clipboard()->SetAsHandle(AFormat, hData);
            }
            else
            Abort();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            GlobalFree((HGLOBAL) hData);
            OutOfMemoryError();
        }
}

Delphi2CB has been corrected so that try...__finally is only used if there are no conflicts.

"[I] couldn't find the "green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer"" - because I didn't post it as an answer to begin with, only as a comment. You can't mark a comment as an accepted answer.
